# Py2EXE Compile Error using Pygame

Tags: python, compilation, compiler-errors, pygame, py2exe

I'm just using Py2exe to compile a simple pygame program into an executable file, but I get the following error:

```
*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included, you may or
may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and make sure you
don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

    OLEAUT32.dll - C:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
    USER32.dll - C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
    IMM32.dll - C:\windows\system32\IMM32.dll
    SHELL32.dll - C:\windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
    ole32.dll - C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
    COMDLG32.dll - C:\windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll
    COMCTL32.dll - C:\windows\system32\COMCTL32.dll
    ADVAPI32.DLL - C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.DLL
    WS2_32.dll - C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
    GDI32.dll - C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
    WINMM.DLL - C:\windows\system32\WINMM.DLL
    KERNEL32.dll - C:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
    SDL_ttf.dll - C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\SDL_ttf.dll
    libogg-0.dll - C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\libogg-0.dll
```

When I try to run the .exe that was created, it doesn't run.  I'm quite familiar with Pygame, but Py2exe is entirely new to me.  Any help is appreciated, as I've looked through the web all morning for a solution.

This is what appears when I try to run it:

```
test.exe:1: RuntimeWarning: import display: No module named _view
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
    test.exe:1: RuntimeWarning: import draw: No module named _view
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
    test.exe:1: RuntimeWarning: import image: No module named _view
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
    test.exe:1: RuntimeWarning: import pixelcopy: No module named _view
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
    test.exe:1: RuntimeWarning: import transform: No module named _view
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "pygame\__init__.pyc", line 70, in __getattr__
    NotImplementedError: display module not available
    (ImportError: No module named _view)
```

Comment: An executable file is created for you, correct? Try running it from the command prompt. What error is it giving you? Note that what you posted isn't necessarily an error message, it's just a little reminder that there are .DLL files that you need to include with the executable file that is created for you for this to run on other machines (since that machine might not have the same DLLs are you).

Comment: What does your setup.py look like? Are you using a proper py2exe pygame recipe? Py2exe is pretty old now

Comment: @jdi  Here is each line:

    `from distutils.core import setup`
    `import py2exe`

    `setup(console=['test.py'])`

Comment: @MarkHildreth I updated the error in the question above.  I got that message running it in the command prompt and outside it.

Yes, that is right, so how would you tell Python to include the DLLs?

Comment: What if you manually `import pygame._view`? This seems like a common error. (I've also switched to using pyInstaller instead of py2app/py2exe/freeze).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your main program:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

It solved my problems when compiling pygame